# Change Keyboard Type on Case

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have two text inputs.

On one screen:

email step:

```
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter E-mail"
          keyboardType="email-address"
        />
```

On another screen:

Unique code:

```
          <TextInput

            keyboardType="phone-pad"

            placeholder="Enter Code"

          />
```

What I have attempted:
I noticed if you hit return on the keyboard it'll dismiss and when I click the text input for the unique code it will give the right keyboard so I tried to dismiss the keyboard on submit but that doesn't dismiss the keyboard.

```
            <TouchableOpacity

              onPress={Keyboard.dismiss && this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
            >

            </TouchableOpacity>
```

If I dismiss it will work but not with my handle submit.
Once the email is submitted and the user hits enter, the keyboard type does not update automatically. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my own foolishness, I realized it should be `Keyboard.dismiss()` which I placed at the top of my handleSubmit() function

When I had it as I did in the question it would dismiss at each touch of the keyboard so that was wrong anyways